# Unexpected Token of While on For Loop

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add images from a folder to an array list however I'm getting an "unexpected token" at the beginning of the for loop, a "cannot resolve symbol 'length' and "identifier expected" on the incrementing of the control variable.

I'm using Intellij as my IDE

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cards {
    File path = new File("/images");
    List imageCollection = new ArrayList();
    File [] files = path.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].isFile()) {
            imageCollection.add(files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `files.length()`

Comment: @bakero98 I'm still getting an error when I use files.length()

Comment: Your code is at top level of your class. You forgot to wrap it in `main` method.

Comment: @Pshemo Nice observation

Comment: @Pshemo thank you! I missed the little things sometimes. Much appreciated!

Comment: BTW `List imageCollection = new ArrayList();` is *raw* type. Please see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321). Use `List<File> imageCollection = new ArrayList<>();` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to declare a method

```
public class Cards {

    void readCollection() { // <-- Here!
        File path = new File("/images");
        List imageCollection = new ArrayList();
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()) {
                imageCollection.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    } // Don't forget the closing bracket
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have a class, you need to place the code within a Java function. Something like this:

```
public class Cards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File path = new File("/images");
        List imageCollection = new ArrayList();
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            if (files[i].isFile()) {
                imageCollection.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```